# How to SetError React Hook form and React-dropzone

Tags: react-hook-form, react-dropzone

I'm working on a React hook form project and I'm using react-dropzone to upload some images, I want to display a React hook form's ERROR when the type of file is not an image, I can console.log Error but I don't know how to use SetError and block form submition until the file format is accepted..

[This is my Sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-pascal-8nb8by?file=/src/File.js)

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to block form submission is to use the `disabled` property of the `input` when the length of the `fileRejections` array is greater than zero:

```js
<input type="submit" disabled={fileRejections.length > 0}/>
```

The whole form code is:

```js
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <section className="container">
        <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} name="upload" />
          <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
          <em>(Only *.jpeg and *.png images will be accepted)</em>
        </div>
        <aside>
          <h4>Accepted files</h4>
          <ul>{acceptedFileItems}</ul>
          <h4>Rejected files</h4>
          <ul>{fileRejectionItems}</ul>
        </aside>
      </section>
      <input type="submit" disabled={fileRejections.length > 0}/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but what about if I want to display an error to prevent user ? because I will have other input fields in my form too :)

Comment: @Tania12 Can you please supplement the question with a description of the error behavior, preferably with a screenshot? Perhaps it will be enough to display the "Rejected files" block with a list of files only in case of an error?

Comment: @Tania12 Perhaps it is better to use the error handling available in react-hook-form, but for this, depending on the situation, you need to register the components of the form, or use Controller.